# RxJS - how to accumulate data and act on it, without multiple callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

So this code runs, but it's firing the callback in .flatmap 5 times:

```
        var i = 0;
        const values = {};
        return this.obsClient.take(5)
            .flatMap(v => {
                const time = Date.now();
                values[i] = {time: time, count: v.clientCount};
                console.log('values => ', values);
                i++;
                return Rx.Observable.timer(100)
            });
```

"values => x" will get logged 5 times.

I thought maybe if I did the following, it would to accumulate all 5 pieces of data before firing the flatMap callback:

```
      var i = 0;
      const values = {};
      return this.obsClient.take(5).takeLast(5)
        .flatMap(v => {
            const time = Date.now();
            values[i] = {time: time, count: v.clientCount};
            console.log('values => ', values);
            i++;
            return Rx.Observable.timer(100)
        });
```

but it still logs "values => x" 5 times. *How can I accumulate the data, and pass all the data to the callback and avoid firing the callback 5 times?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the last five items in the sequence at once:

```
  return this.obsClient
              .takeLast(5)
              .toArray()
              .flatMap(arr => { /*arr will be an array of the last five items in the sequence */ })
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [`bufferCount`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount):

```
return this.obsClient.bufferCount(5).flatMap(buffer => {
  console.log(`buffer => ${buffer}`);
  return Rx.Observable.timer(100);
});
```

> Buffers the source Observable values until the size hits the maximum `bufferSize` given.

Comment: note; `bufferCount` will emit a value every time its count has been reached. If your intention is to have exactly 5 items and then unsubscribe it might be better to use `.take(5).toArray()` to emit one value containing an array of your 5 elements.